# WCF Resources for SOA Design

Tags: wcf, soa, datacontract, service-design

I am looking for best resources and books for the following specific programming tasks. Could you please provide them?

Note: I think, this question is suitable for stack overflow forum since it is addressing the specific programming tasks.

•   Handling relationship bewteen OOP and SOA.

•   Design entities for extensibility.  Extend Data contracts without affecting consumers of the service.

•   Compose entities from standard elements. When possible, use standard elements to compose the complex types used by your service.

•   Versioning of contracts.

•   Ensure that the service can detect and manage repeated messages (idempotency).

Comment: I think, this question is suitable for stack overflow forum since it is addressing the specific programming tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't answer your question fully, but this microsoft link has some best practices for WCF versioning:-
[Guidelines and Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731197.aspx)